# Converting value types to Protobuffer's `Any` Type

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

According to Protobuffer's documentation, there's an `Any` type (`google/protobuf/any.proto`) that should technically be able to carry any type of data.

However, when I compile my `.proto` file to `C#`, the generated code for the `Any` type is NOT `object` and instead is `Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Any`. The `Pack` method associated with the `Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Any` type accepts an argument that implement `IMessage` and that means any types that is wrapped in another type can be passed as an unknown (`Any` type) object but I cannot use it with a value type directly. (If my understanding is correct, the `Any` type would be most useless feature of the Protobuffer!)

Is there any way that I can associate a value type (string, int, uint, bool, etc.) with an `Any` type without having to wrap it in another message?

Answer (score 0):

My conclusion is that the `Any` type implementation by Google is very useless. A  better and more flexible solution is to re-create it from the scratch using the following message:

```
message Any {
    string type = 1;
    bytes value = 2;
}
```

This will increase the size of the data as the typename will be repeated for any instance of the `Any` type. However, I think Google's implementation also follows a similar approach as I found a `TypeURL` associated with the underlying bytes.

This method at least allows for simply converting any C# type to the `Any` message type.